# "calling thread must be STA" error when trying to access an object from another window

Tags: c#

I have an application that does data acquisition over a serial port (modbus), and I use a BackgroundWorker object to call the device because otherwise it takes time and freezes my UI.
The problem arises when I open a new WPF window and set its DataContext to be the object I'm updating (I want to use this window to get a detailed view of the device - status, charts, bargraphs). 
Is there a way of using my data object in another window or should I consider making my app a single windowed one?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a WPF Window from a WinForms BackgroundWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008696/creating-a-wpf-window-from-a-winforms-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the discussion on a similar question that I asked.  I think it might help you out. [STAThread missing but it is there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584434/stathread-missing-but-it-is-there) I know the title seems a little different, but a lot of the ideas presented might help you out as well.